# Has an astronaut had a blood sample taken while in space?

Tags: astronauts, medical, experiment

Has any astronaut had a sample of their blood taken while in space?  This may be as part of a scientific experiment, or for their own health.  If yes, was the sample analyzed while in space, or was it returned to Earth for analysis?

Comment: Do you think the current answer is sufficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [here's a video of an astronaut drawing blood in space](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mUuRzZbM4uY) and generally they freeze the samples and send them back to Earth for analyses, [but there is also a Bio-Analyzer on the ISS so they don't have to return samples.](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/news/bioanalyzer-biomedical-analysis) Astronauts have to take blood, urine and saliva tests which are normally sent back to Earth soon before the astronauts themselves return, for freshness...

Comment: A very quick google yielded those answers, showing little research..

Comment: Just read a [meta post](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/962/are-we-interested-in-moderating-the-quality-of-questions-here), my understanding is that I should have just answered the question and not commented the answer, my bad. I will remove my comment (and edit your answer accordingly)